# if (QString.contains()) does not work correctly, correct using temp bool variable

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to detect a string in a file. I use the .contains method from QString. This works as expected when I do this:

```
bool result;
QString line = in.readLine();
QString target("999");
result = line.contains(target,Qt::CaseInsensitive);
qDebug() << result;
if (result)
{
    qDebug() << "Comment found" << line;
    QString line = in.readLine();
    qDebug() << "Comment: " << line;
}
```

But it matches way more often when I do this:

```
bool result;
QString line = in.readLine();
QString target("999");
if (line.contains(target,Qt::CaseInsensitive));
{
    qDebug() << "Comment found" << line;
    QString line = in.readLine();
    qDebug() << "Comment: " << line;
}
```

Testfile:

```
999
This file is edited by ........
  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1014
  9
$ACADMAINTVER
 70
     9
  9
$DWGCODEPAGE
  3
ANSI_1252
  9
$INSBASE
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
  9
$EXTMIN
 10
1.000000000000000E+20
 20
1.000000000000000E+20
 30
1.000000000000000E+20
  9
$EXTMAX
```

Output from first program:

```
"O:/<<snipped>>.DXF"
true
Comment found "999"
Comment:  "This file is edited by ........"
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

Output from second program:

```
true
Comment found "999"
Comment:  "This file is edited by ........"
false
Comment found "  0"
Comment:  "SECTION"
false
Comment found "  2"
Comment:  "HEADER"
false
Comment found "  9"
Comment:  "$ACADVER"
false
Comment found "  1"
Comment:  "AC1014"
false
Comment found "  9"
Comment:  "$ACADMAINTVER"
false
Comment found " 70"
Comment:  "     9"
false
Comment found "  9"
Comment:  "$DWGCODEPAGE"
false
Comment found "  3"
Comment:  "ANSI_1252"
false
Comment found "  9"
Comment:  "$INSBASE"
false
Comment found " 10"
Comment:  "0.0"
false
Comment found " 20"
Comment:  "0.0"
false
Comment found " 30"
Comment:  "0.0"
false
Comment found "  9"
Comment:  "$EXTMIN"
false
Comment found " 10"
Comment:  "1.000000000000000E+20"
false
Comment found " 20"
Comment:  "1.000000000000000E+20"
false
Comment found " 30"
Comment:  "1.000000000000000E+20"
false
Comment found "  9"
Comment:  "$EXTMAX"
```

Full code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName;
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open File"),"","Dxf Files(*.dxf);;All files(*.*)");
    qDebug()<<fileName;

    bool result;
    QFile sourceFile;
    QFile targetFile;
    sourceFile.setFileName(fileName);
    if (sourceFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream in(&sourceFile);
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            QString target("999");
            result = line.contains(target,Qt::CaseInsensitive);
            qDebug() << result;
            if (line.contains(target,Qt::CaseInsensitive)); //is true for all strings with numbers?
            //if (result)
            {
                qDebug() << "Comment found" << line;
                QString line = in.readLine(); //does this construction crash when the input file contains 999 as the last line of the file?
                qDebug() << "Comment: " << line;
            }
        }
        sourceFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<fileName << " could not be opened";
    }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong? I run Qt 5.7.0 on windows 7
Kind regards,
Cedric

Comment: You have a typo. The semi-colon at the end of this line: `if (line.contains(target,Qt::CaseInsensitive));` is defeating the `if` statement.

Comment: `Qt::CaseInsensitive` is useless when comparing with `"999"`

Comment: It keeps me wondering why the makers of C thought it was a good idea to allow an empty statement after if, for, while. (Yes, I have been bitten by this, hasn't everybody?)

Comment: Hi @Prutser. I just rolled back your last edit. Please read this short explanation to learn what to do when somebody answered your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the full snippet, you have a semicolon `;` at the end of the line:

```
if (line.contains(target,Qt::CaseInsensitive));
```

As a result, `if` statement does nothing and the following block is always executed:

```
{
    qDebug() << "Comment found" << line;
    QString line = in.readLine(); //does this construction crash when the input file contains 999 as the last line of the file?
    qDebug() << "Comment: " << line;
}
```